# Python argparse: How to change `--add` into `add` while still being an optional argument?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I want this functionality:

```
$ python program.py add Peter 
'Peter' was added to the list of names.
```

I can achieve this with `--add` instead of `add` like this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--add", help="Add a new name to the list of names",
                    action="store")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.add:
   print "'%s' was added to the list of names." % args.add
else:
   print "Just executing the program baby."
```

Such that:

```
$ python program.py --add Peter
'Peter' was added to the list of names.
```

But when I change `--add` to `add` it is no longer optional, how can I still let it be optional yet not have those `--` signs? (preferably also using the `argparse` library)

Comment: the `--` prefix is used in `argparse` because it tries to enforce a consistent style across all programs, (optional arguments look like they are optional).  If you want to use a very different style for the way you handle arguments, you might not really want `argparse` at all.

Comment: Good point, what solution would you deem most suited outside the `argparse` library that doesn't enforce this style of optional arguments?

Comment: well, I wouldn't go against the recommended style at all.  That just makes things confusing @.@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, is actually called "positional arguments".
You can parse them like this:

```
import argparse                                                             
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()                                             
parser.add_argument("cmd", help="Execute a command",                           
                    action="store", nargs='*')                                 
args = parser.parse_args()                                                     
if args.cmd:                                                                   
    cmd, name = args.cmd                                                       
    print "'%s' was '%s'-ed to the list of names." % (name, cmd)               
else:                                                                          
    print "Just executing the program baby."
```

Which gives you the ability to specify different actions:

```
$ python g.py add peter
'peter' was 'add'-ed to the list of names.

$ python g.py del peter
'peter' was 'del'-ed to the list of names.

$ python g.py 
Just executing the program baby.
```

Comment: Thanks, this does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sub-commands](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands) to achieve this behaviour. Try something like the following

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='Subcommands',
    description='valid subcommands',
    help='additional help')

addparser = subparsers.add_parser('add')
addparser.add_argument('names', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.names:
    print "'%s' was added to the list of names." % args.names
else:
    print "Just executing the program baby."
```

Note that the use of `nargs='*'` means that `args.names` is now a list, unlike your `args.add`, so you can add an arbitrary number of names following `add` (you'll have to modify how you handle this argument). The above can then be called as follows:

```
$ python test.py add test
'['test']' was added to the list of names.

$ python test.py add test1 test2
'['test1', 'test2']' was added to the list of names.
```

Comment: This is very nice, but `python test.py` gives a `too few arguments` error. I would like to make that `add` argument optional.

Comment: That is a good point. Unfortunately when using sub commands at least one of the sub commands must be specified - it is not possible to have optional sub commands at the moment. Is there a reason you want to change `--add` to `add`. It seems that your best bet is to leave `--add` as it is.

Comment: The reason why I want to do that is because I find it cleaner and less confusing for new users. As an example, see the taskwarrior program. You can also reserve these signs for a new type of optional arguments that have similar functionality accross other optional arguments.
Example: `python example.py -v command_A`
`python example.py -v command_B`
Here `-v` would have the same functionality for two different optional commands `command_A` and `command_B`.

Comment: When you run e.g. `$ git`, the git command on itself does not do anything. My program should run by just typing the name. This makes more sense for my program because it is very limited as opposed to git, there are possibly only three optional agrguments I want to implement. I.m.o. for programs with very few optional arguments forcing to use extra arguments each time is too verbose. Especially if these extra commands run code that will probably only have to be run once or twice in the lifetime of the program for a particular user.